# Weather Api Right/wrong city filter not working (Django project - views.py file below)

Tags: django, api, weather

weatherapi.com giving me two different replies for city that exist or city that does not exist

**#when i am trying to add Wrong city i am getting this replay from api.**
{'error': {'code': 1006, 'message': 'No matching location found.'}}

**#when i am writing right city name i am geting this reply from api.**
{'location': {'name': 'Texas City', 'region': 'Texas', 'country': 'United States of America', 'lat': 29.38, 'lon': -94.9, 'tz_id': 'America/Chicago', 'localtime_epoch': 1670842210, 'localtime': '2022-12-12 4:50'}, 'current': {'last_updated_epoch': 1670841900, 'last_updated': '2022-12-12 04:45', 'temp_c': 18.9, 'temp_f': 66.0, 'is_day': 0, 'condition': {'text': 'Overcast', 'icon': '//cdn.weatherapi.com/weather/64x64/night/122.png', 'code': 1009}, 'wind_mph': 9.4, 'wind_kph': 15.1, 'wind_degree': 60, 'wind_dir': 'ENE', 'pressure_mb': 1016.0, 'pressure_in': 30.01, 'precip_mm': 0.0, 'precip_in': 0.0, 'humidity': 93, 'cloud': 100, 'feelslike_c': 18.9, 'feelslike_f': 66.0, 'vis_km': 11.0, 'vis_miles': 6.0, 'uv': 1.0, 'gust_mph': 10.1, 'gust_kph': 16.2, 'air_quality': {'co': 260.3999938964844, 'no2': 17.0, 'o3': 1.100000023841858, 'so2': 6.5, 'pm2_5': 4.0, 'pm10': 5.800000190734863, 'us-epa-index': 1, 'gb-defra-index': 1}}}

**How can i filter by using "code: 1006" that city exist or not exist before saving it to database?**

**Code A** working fine if city does not exist but showing key error if add a right city

**code B** working if I add city that exist but if i try to add a city does not exist, showing Eror key error condition

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
from .models import City
from .forms import CityForm

# Create your views here.

def index (request):
    url = 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=403d3701b46c42a2bac104734221012&q={}&aqi=yes'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_city = form.cleaned_data['name']
            existing_city_count= City.objects.filter(name = new_city).count()
            if existing_city_count ==0:
                r=requests.get(url.format(new_city)).json()
                
                #Code A ___________
                #error_code = r['error']['code'] == 1006:
                #if error_code = 1006:
                    #print("City does not exist")
                #else:
                    #form.save()
                    
                #Code B _____________   
                #right_code = r['current']['condition']['code']
                #if right_code is not 1006:
                    #form.save()
                #else:
                    #print("city does not exist")
            else:
                err_msg = "City Already exist in the database"
    
    
    form = CityForm()
    cities = City.objects.all()
    wd = []
    for city in cities:
        r = requests.get(url.format(city)).json()
        cw ={
            'city' : r['location']['name'],
            'temp' : r['current']['temp_c'],
            'desc' : r['current']['condition']['text'],
            'icon' :r['current']['condition']['icon'],
            'code' : r['current']['condition']['code'],
            }
        wd.append(cw)
        #print(wd)
    
    context = { 'cw':wd, 'addform': form}
    
    return render(request, 'wa/index.html', context)
```

Comment: don't show your api key in a public question site...

Comment: Ok i will remember next time, it will be a good practice for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to check whether **its an error case or success case as response from weather API then accordingly** you can handle the cases. i have not used try catch in below code which you can update further to make it more robust also i have changed the city existence check in db **from count to exists** as it is more efficient way.
**Please check commented parts i have mentioned details there** and feel free to connect any further details required.
***please upvote if my answer helped you thanks and happy coding!! :)***

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import CityForm
import requests
from .models import City

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    url = 'http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=403d3701b46c42a2bac104734221012&q={}&aqi=yes'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        code=''
        form = CityForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_city = form.cleaned_data['city']
            # existing_city_count= City.objects.filter(city = new_city).count() remove count and used exist to check whether a city exist in database or not as exist is more efficient that count
            if not City.objects.filter(city = new_city).exists():
                r=requests.get(url.format(new_city)).json()
                #Code A ___________
                if 'error' in r:#checking the key error exist  in response from get  or not
                    code = r['error']['code']
                #Code B _____________   
                if 'current' in r: #checking the key current exist  in result  or not
                    code =  r['current']['condition']['code']

                if code != 1006: #checking if code is not 1006 save city to database
                    form.save()      
                else:
                    print("city does not exist")
            else:
                err_msg = "City Already exist in the database"
            return render(request,'index.html',{'form':CityForm()})
    else:
       return render(request,'index.html',{'form':CityForm()})
```

Comment: Your code writing style is very elegant and very easy to process. Thank you very much for giving me the right direction.  Do you have any youtube channel where you share your knowledge to encourage others? It will be very appreciated if you share the link. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for appreciating and kind words ! :) sorry I don't have any youtube channel but in future if i get time will surely do. Its feels great when we help each other. Happy coding!